# Ssh reverse tunneling command

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, remote-access

I am  newbie in python and networking.I wanted to connect to my local machine through a proxy server in cloud.any help will be highly appreciating.

Answer (score 3):

```
ssh -f -R <cloud_port>:localhost:<local_port> <username@cloud_ip> -N
```

-N : don't login, just create tunnel

Above command creates `cloud_port` in your `cloud(username@cloud_port)` and `local_port` in your local machine.
So, any request from cloud at port `<cloud_port>` will be redirected to local port `<local_port>`, if your local system is connected to www.

e.g.

```
cloud_port : 6999
local_port : 22
```

then you can login from cloud at  to local port 22(ssh login)

Enjoy Coding